# Dealing with Spatial Autocorrelation in a Gamma GLMM

Tags: r, lme4, mixed-models, nlme, glmm

## Problem Overview

I am working with a dataset that examines plant growth in relation to
various factors, including sea ice extent (SeaIce) at 14 different
sampling sites. To analyze the data, I am using a Gamma Generalized
Linear Mixed Model (GLMM) with a log-link function. However, I am
concerned about spatial autocorrelation in the model’s residuals and I
am unsure about the best approach to address this issue.

To solve this, I am utilizing the
[`DHARMa`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/DHARMa/index.html)
package along with
[`lme4`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lme4/index.html) for
model fitting.

```r
library(DHARMa)
library(lme4)
library(MASS)
library(gstat)
library(dplyr)
library(sf)
library(sp)
```

You can find the dataset for this model in this [GitHub
repository](https://github.com/derek-corcoran-barrios/SeaIceQuestion).

```r
FinalDataset <- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/derek-corcoran-barrios/SeaIceQuestion/master/FinalDataset.csv")
```

### Current Model Structure

#### Response Variable

- **Growth:** Represents the annual growth increment of each individual
  plant.

#### Predictors

- **SeaIce.s:** Sea ice extent per year per site, a primary predictor of
  interest (scaled).
- **age:** Age of each individual plant for each measured year, included
  as an interaction with SeaIce.s due to a biological relationship
  between plant age and growth.

#### Random Effects

- **Site:** A factor representing the 14 sampling sites with varying
  distances between them. I include a random slope `(SeaIce.s | Site)`
  to account for different slopes in the growth-sea ice relationship per
  site.
- **year:** The study covers the years from 1983 to 2015 and is included
  as a random effect `(1 | year)`.
- **Individual:** A factor representing each individual plant measured.

#### Model

```r
fullmod <- glmer(Growth ~ SeaIce.s * age + (SeaIce.s | Site) + (1 | year) + (1 | Individual), data = FinalDataset, family = Gamma(link = "log"), control = glmerControl(optimizer = "bobyqa", optCtrl = list(maxfun = 2e5)))
```

## Primary Concern

My main concern is how to properly account for spatial autocorrelation
within this model. I can see that there is a problem when I use this
code in dHARMA.

```r
res2_null <- simulateResiduals(fullmod)
res3_null <- recalculateResiduals(res2_null, group = FinalDataset$Site)
locs_null <- FinalDataset %>% group_by(Site) %>% summarise(across(c(Latitude, Longitude), mean))
testSpatialAutocorrelation(res3_null, x = locs_null$Longitude, y = locs_null$Latitude)
```

[image]

```
## 
##  DHARMa Moran's I test for distance-based autocorrelation
## 
## data:  res3_null
## observed = 0.343448, expected = -0.076923, sd = 0.150983, p-value =
## 0.005365
## alternative hypothesis: Distance-based autocorrelation
```

As you can see by this result, there is a high spatial autocorrelation.

### Some things I have tried:

#### Attempted Solution 1

One of the solutions I’ve attempted following [this
question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70687031/how-to-resolve-glmm-residuals-pattern-spatial-correlation-and-zero-distance-er)
to include latitude and longitude as fixed effects. However, when I test
for spatial autocorrelation using testSpatialAutocorrelation() in the
DHARMa package, I still get a significant Moran’s I with the model that
includes latitude and longitude.

```r
LonLatmod <- glmer(Growth ~ SeaIce.s * age + Latitude + Longitude + (SeaIce.s | Site) + (1 | year) + (1 | Individual), data = FinalDataset, family = Gamma(link = "log"), control = glmerControl(optimizer = "bobyqa", optCtrl = list(maxfun = 2e5)))

res <-  simulateResiduals(LonLatmod)
res2 <- recalculateResiduals(res, group = FinalDataset$Site)
locs_latlon <- FinalDataset %>% group_by(Site) %>% summarise(across(c(Latitude, Longitude), mean))
testSpatialAutocorrelation(res2, x =  locs_latlon$Longitude, y = locs_latlon$Latitude)
```

[image]

```
## 
##  DHARMa Moran's I test for distance-based autocorrelation
## 
## data:  res2
## observed = 0.382948, expected = -0.076923, sd = 0.150649, p-value =
## 0.002269
## alternative hypothesis: Distance-based autocorrelation
```

#### Attempted Solution 2

I also tried using glmmPQL() in the MASS package. But I have not been
able to get this to work either, due to various errors, even without
adding the correlation structure. Example below:

```r
formula_glmmPQL <- as.formula("Growth ~ SeaIce.s * age")
model_glmmPQL <- glmmPQL(formula_glmmPQL,
                         random = list(~ SeaIce.s|Site, 
                                      ~ 1|year, 
                                      ~1| Individual),
                         data = FinalDataset,
                         na.action=na.omit,
                         family = Gamma(link = "log"))

#Error in pdFactor.pdLogChol(X[[i]], ...) :
#NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 3)
```

#### Attempted Solution 3

I have also tried using variogram() in the gstat package, but I am
unsure how to interpret the shape of the variogram and what to change in
my model based on this.

```r
FinalDatasetSF <- st_as_sf(FinalDataset, coords = c("Longitude", "Latitude"), crs = st_crs(4326))

null_mod <- variogram(log(Growth) ~ 1, FinalDatasetSF)

Abn_fit_null <- fit.variogram(null_mod, model = vgm(1, "Sph", 
                                              700, 1))
plot(null_mod, model=Abn_fit_null)
```

I have also explored the corAR1() function in the nlme package, but it
appears to be incompatible with glmer() models.

## Edit

I added the solution by @SarahS with and without the Latitude and
Longitude as fixed effects

```r
require(glmmTMB)
# Set up the necessary variables
FinalDataset$pos <- numFactor(FinalDataset$Latitude, FinalDataset$Longitude)
FinalDataset$group <- factor(rep(1, nrow(FinalDataset)))
# Fit model
TestA <- glmmTMB(Growth ~ SeaIce.s * age + Latitude + Longitude + (SeaIce.s | Site) + (1 | year) + (1 | Individual) + 1 + exp(pos + 0 | group), data = FinalDataset, family = Gamma(link = "log"))


TestB <- glmmTMB(Growth ~ SeaIce.s * age + Latitude + Longitude + (SeaIce.s | Site) + (1 | year) + (1 | Individual) + 1 + exp(pos + 0 | group), data = FinalDataset, family = Gamma(link = "log"))
```

However neither of these solve the spatial autocorrelation issue as seen below:

```r
res <-  simulateResiduals(TestA)
res2 <- recalculateResiduals(res, group = FinalDataset$Site)

locs_latlon <- FinalDataset %>% group_by(Site) %>% summarise(across(c(Latitude, Longitude), mean))

testSpatialAutocorrelation(res2, x =  locs_latlon$Longitude, y = locs_latlon$Latitude)
```

[image]

```
## 
##  DHARMa Moran's I test for distance-based autocorrelation
## 
## data:  res2
## observed = 0.409445, expected = -0.076923, sd = 0.151346, p-value =
## 0.001311
## alternative hypothesis: Distance-based autocorrelation
```

and here

```r
res <-  simulateResiduals(TestB)
res2 <- recalculateResiduals(res, group = FinalDataset$Site)

testSpatialAutocorrelation(res2, x =  locs_latlon$Longitude, y = locs_latlon$Latitude)
```

[image]

```
## 
##  DHARMa Moran's I test for distance-based autocorrelation
## 
## data:  res2
## observed = 0.409445, expected = -0.076923, sd = 0.151346, p-value =
## 0.001311
## alternative hypothesis: Distance-based autocorrelation
```

### Request for Suggestions

I would be interested in any suggestions or insights on how to
effectively address spatial autocorrelation in my current modeling
approach.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, That is a good point, however I have seen that @ben-bolker answer very similar questions here, basically the structure of the model I understand. The issue is how to add the spatial autocorrelation structure to this particular model, however if more people think the same as you I will migrate this question

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the [spatial autocorrelation adjustment](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/glmmTMB/vignettes/covstruct.html) in [glmmTMB](https://glmmtmb.github.io/glmmTMB/index.html)?

I believe the code would be

```
install.packages("glmmTMB"); require(glmmTMB)
# Set up the necessary variables
FinalDataset$pos <- numFactor(FinalDataset$Latitude, FinalDataset$Longitude)
FinalDataset$group <- factor(rep(1, nrow(FinalDataset)))
# Fit model
glmmTMB(Growth ~ SeaIce.s * age + (SeaIce.s | Site) + (1 | year) + (1 | Individual) + 1 + exp(pos + 0 | group), data = FinalDataset, family = Gamma(link = "log"))
```

Comment: thanks @SarahS, this is a great start, however, for some reason this does not deal with the spatial autocorrelation, it is still there, I made an edit with your solution

Comment: I actually fit your original model, and it looks like there is singular fit from the SeaIce|Site random effect. If you remove that parameter, there is no longer singular fit. It also seems like a negative binomial distribution might fit your data better; if I use that distribution; there is no longer singular fit. However, fitting the spatial-autocorrelation adjusted model does result in singular fit again. This is likely due to the fact that site is a spatial variable, so it captures some amount of the spatial autocorrelation and therefore the model can't fit the spatial parameter correctly.

Comment: Removing the random slopes interaction helps, but I got a similar result in that including the spatial autocorrelation didn't actually improve the autocorrelation of the residuals. It could be because you have 4 sites that are very close together and have high spatial autocorrelation, then the rest of your sites do not. I think I read something somewhere that including spatial autocorrelation in the model doesn't necessary show in the residuals, but it does adjust the parameter estimates to incorporate that potential autocorrelation, but of course now I can't recall where I read it.